# How to default an EditText to integer but allow decimal input?

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, double

I am using an EditText to allow a user to input a value that is stored in a Double.

However, by default, Doubles look like "0.0" and it's a little annoying for a user to backspace over the extra decimal if it's not used. Is there a way to force-display whole numbers to look like "0" and only show the decimal if the user actually decides to use it?

Current code:

```
        myEditText = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.my_edittext);
        myEditText.setText(myVariable + "");
        myEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                String temp = s.toString();
                if (s.length() > 0){
                    if (OtherMethods.isDouble(temp)) {
                        myVariable = Double.parseDouble(temp);
                    }
                    else {
                        myVariable = 0.0;
                    }
                }
                else {
                    myVariable = 0.0;
                }
            }
        });
```

The XML:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/my_edittext"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Input Value"
    android:imeOptions="actionDone"/>
```

Comment: if you want default then set `inpuType` to `text` so the user can set fields as he/she want.

Comment: @NJ That would allow for nonnumeric values

Answer (score 1):

1. Parsing Double to String, then String to Int:

   ```
   String stringparsed = YourDouble + "";
   int intparsed = Integer.parseInt(stringparsed);
   ```
2. Using substring to cut the string from a startIndex to finalIndex:

   ```
   String stringparsed = YourDouble + "";
   String final = stringparsed.substring(0,1);   //for example, if the double was    0.0, the result is 0
   ```

Answer (score 1):

To achieve this you can use `NumberFormat`

```
    EditText yourEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextID);
    //dummy data, will have user's value
    double aDouble = 4.0;

    //formats to show decimal
    NumberFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("#0");

    //this will show "4"
    yourEditText.setText(formatter.format(aDouble));
```

Make sure to validate the user's input. Also, this will only modify what is displayed and not the value itself.

Comment: Upon re-reading the question, my solution will only work if you are displaying the value after the user entered it, and will not really allow the formatting of the value as it's being entered.

Comment: I added some code to the original post. Problem with your approach is that even if the number has a decimal portion, it will get displayed as an int