# Conditional NumberFormatter?

Tags: java, format, number-formatting, numberformatter

Is there a way to make a NumberFormatter that does the following:

1. If the Double is a whole number like 5.0, display "5"
2. If the Double is a decimal like 5.6, display "5.6"

Comment: The answer is absolutely yes.  You can write your own subclass of `NumberFormatter` to do whatever you like.

Comment: I had tried solutions from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41657200/how-to-default-an-edittext-to-integer-but-allow-decimal-input/41657315 but nothing is working so I am trying a format solution

Comment: @DavidWallace I'm sure it can be done, but if I knew how to do it in this case I wouldn't have asked

Comment: By the way, do you mean the Swing `NumberFormatter` class, or do you actually mean `NumberFormat`?

Comment: I don't know the difference; whatever will work

Comment: Then your question is unclear.  Are you looking for a `NumberFormatter` or  a `NumberFormat`?  If you don't say what you're going to _do_ with it, then how can anyone tell you which one will actually "work"?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to nicely format floating numbers to String without unnecessary decimal 0?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/703396/how-to-nicely-format-floating-numbers-to-string-without-unnecessary-decimal-0)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
double someNum = 5.6d;
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.#");
String num = df.format(someNum);
if (num.substring(num.length - 1).equals("0")) {
    num = num.substring(0, num.length - 2);
}
System.out.println(num);
```

The `DecimalFormat` instance formats the double into a string.  The code checks the tenth place of precision, i.e. the first digit to the right of the decimal place, and if it be zero, then it shows only whole numbers.  Otherwise, it shows the full precision.

Comment: Doesn't this truncate any 0? Like if a user entered 120, it'd be struck down to 12?

Comment: Did you actually test my code?  Your question only asked about numbers having digit of precision past the decimal point.

Comment: Well I usually look at the code for a second or two before I test it, but yes, it does seem to work, I just don't see how

Comment: Then teach me to fish rather than being condescending towards my otherwise reasonable questions

Comment: @KaliMa I added an explanation.  So you like Planet of the Apes movies?

Comment: Indiana Jones technically

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but this should do exactly what you asked:

```
    var myNumber:Double = 0.0  // set to 5.0 or 5.6 to see result

    let formatter = NumberFormatter()
    formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 4
    let x = formatter.string(from: NSNumber(value: myNumber)) ?? "$\(myNumber)"
    print("x = \(x)")
```